# mysqli array -> query not attaining correct data

Tags: php, mysqli, echo

my `mysqli_fetch_array(mysqi_query($db, $query))` doesn't appear to be getting the correct information from the database, and therefore, the PHP application is not working as it should.

Here are the queries,

```
<?php
if($_GET){
$current = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from `tbl_user` WHERE `userid` = '".$_GET['userid']."'"));
$currentperms  = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from `tbl_perms` WHERE `userid` = '".$_GET['userid']."'"));
} 
?>
```

Concurrently, the `if ($current['userid'] == "1") {echo(" selected ");}` isn't outputting anything at all, so the correct option isn't selected in the SELECT tag.

So, where: I'd expect:
    echo($currentperms['newapp']);
not to equal 1, becuase it is set so in the database, the result of which is "1". I have test this by echoing the string gained. Newapp is not a column in the table either, so it shouldn't be returning "1" as a result.

With this:

```
 if $current['userid'] == "1") {
 echo(" selected ");
 }
```

Nothing is being echoed, however, the variable has been used in the script earlier, and the output of which is "1".

Please help me, I'm going through the roof :|

@sasa: output:
Success!Array ( [0] => 1 [userid] => 1 [1] => shamil.nunhuck [username] => shamil.nunhuck [2] => Shamil Nunhuck [userfullname] => Shamil Nunhuck [3] => shamil.nunhuck@localhost [useremail] => shamil.nunhuck@localhost [4] => 6363d731bd7492fe4c33fc3d90fd61bc [userpassword] => 6363d731bd7492fe4c33fc3d90fd61bc [5] => 1 [userlevel] => 1 [6] => Administrator [usertitle] => Administrator [7] => 1 [tos] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 1 [userid] => 1 [1] => 0 [ptodo] => 0 [2] => 0 [usercp] => 0 [3] => 0 [pm] => 0 [4] => 0 [bug] => 0 [5] => 0 [abug] => 0 [6] => 0 [admincp] => 0 [7] => 0 [intmgs] => 0 [8] => 0 [adduser] => 0 [9] => 0 [pass] => 0 [10] => 0 [useredit] => 0 [11] => 0 [listuser] => 0 [12] => 0 [newapp] => 0 )

Comment: Whole script did not come out :Z

Comment: Please use correct code indention and use the code mode of Stack Overflow. Your code is just not readable right now.

Comment: I've tried, but becuase the code uses a lot of html, it is being parsed.

Comment: Not if you mark it as code. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
//  I put some echo for testing
if(!empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
    $sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from tbl_user WHERE userid = $id LIMIT 1");
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($db) == 0) {
        echo "There is no user with that id";
    } else {
        $current = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
        $currentperms  = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from tbl_perms WHERE userid = $id"));
        echo "Success!";
        // Or try to print result
        print_r($current);
        print_r($currentperms);
    }
} else {
    echo "There is no user id";
}
```

OR maybe just a syntax error:

> With this:
>
> ```
>  if $current['userid'] == "1") {
>  echo(" selected ");
>  }
> ```

It should be:

```
if($current['userid'] == 1) {
    echo(" selected ");
}
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_affected_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in /home/radonsys/public_html/control/useredit.php on line 11

Nope. Line 11 is:
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($sql) == 0) {

Comment: Nope, that's present in the code here - must have accidentally removed it when copying and paste.

Comment: Try to use mysql_fetch_assoc instead mysql_fetch_array, or try $current['userid'] == 1 without quotes...

Comment: Well, the echoed stuff is correct, but the checkbox, and statement:$currentperms['newapp'], still show 1 :|

Comment: Have you thought any more on this?

Answer (score 2):

If the issue is that the database is returning incorrect information it's probably best you just post the mysql portion of the code (esp. the query), the current results and what results you expected to see.

also fyi, I hope your parsing your $_GET and $_POST vars prior to dumping them into that query. Passing them straight into the SQL like that is not a good idea.

Comment: Updated the post. I currently don't dump the post and vars, however, this is currently being revised throughout the whole of the PHP application.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I follow the question, but you appear to be saying that the result of `$current['userid'] == "1"` is false, despite `$current['userid']` printing out as "1", correct?

If that's the case, it's possible there's some whitespace or other junk getting into the value which causes the comparison to fail, although I doubt that's the case if `userid` is auto-generated by the database.

You can verify this by more thoroughly inspecting the value, e.g.

```
var_dump( $current['userid'] ); // Check for whitespace
echo strlen( $current['userid'] ); // Is this greater than 1?
```

Comment: Results:
string(1) "1" 
Echo  - 1

It's a match!